# Debug iPhone Chrome

Tags: ios, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to use chrome://inspect to debug Chrome running on an iPhone that is plugged in via USB?

Basically I just want to use Chrome on my laptop to debug, not Safari.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. The reason for that is that due to the limitations of iOS Chrome uses [WebKit](http://www.webkit.org/) while on all other platforms it employs [Blink](http://www.chromium.org/blink) to render web pages. Chrome DevTools' core which resides in [Blink](http://www.chromium.org/blink) hence it is not available on iOS.